# Drawing with Core Graphics in a CALayer

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation, core-graphics, calayer

I'm trying to get my head around Core Graphics and Core Animation.  I understand the following:

- Using `UIView`, I can draw with Core Graphics by overriding `drawRect`.
- I can create multiple `CALayer`'s and set their properties and have them added

My questions are:
  - If I create a `CALayer` from scratch (not using something like  `CALayer *myLayer = myUIView.layer`), what is the approach to draw in that `CALayer`?
 - What's the CALayer's equivalent of `drawRect` for UIView?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do custom drawing you have two options:

1. Subclass `CALayer` and implement `-drawInContext:`.
2. Make your own class that serves as your layer's delegate to perform the Quartz routines. It should implement `-drawLayer:inContext:`.

You should add your custom layer as a sublayer to your `UIView`'s layer. You should take a spin through `CALayer`'s doc pages for some rules about how to interact with the view's layer.

Comment: I just read you can make your custom layer the UIView's layer by subclassing UIView and implementing +layerClass to return your custom layer class. You would do this instead of adding your custom layer as a sublayer of the view's layer (whew).